# Jquery submit not working when I add a handler.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bunch of checkboxes on a page and I want to auto-submit anytime one of them is modified, and capture the response.  If I run this code I can see the first console message, but not the second.  It seems like the form is never submitted.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.project_checkbox').change(function(){
                console.log('this does get called');
                $(this).parent().submit(function() {
                    console.log('this never gets called');
                    return false;
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

If I remove the handler and run this instead the form submits and my browser opens up the URL of the appropriate form.  I can tell from the output that it's reading the correct vale for the checkbox:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.project_checkbox').change(function(){
                console.log('this does get called');
                $(this).parent().submit();
            });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone tell why adding the handler in this case would kill the submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.submit( function() { } )` is different from `.submit()`. The first one sets the function that gets called when the form is submitted, equivalent to `.bind('submit', function() { } )`. The second one actually triggers the submit event, equivalent to `.trigger('submit')`. See http://api.jquery.com/submit/ for more info.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I wasn't usnderstanding the distinction between the two.  Now that I re-read the submit API page with this info it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding an event to `$(this).parent()`, so it will only be executed when the form is submitted. To submit the form, just call the method directly after the binding: `$(this).parent().submit`.